# how to add looping that ask yes or no after the calculation has been executed?

Tags: java

I don't know how to insert a looping that ask 'yes or no' in  this coding. Supposedly I should put a question at the end off this coding for the cylinder class only for ' would you like to repeat this calculation' but I still do not know how to insert it.

```
import java.util.*;

public class cylinder extends circle {

    public cylinder(double r, double a) 
    {
        super(r, a);
    }

    private double  height;
    private double radius;
    private double volume;

    public double getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight()
    {
        Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Height : ");
        double height = r.nextDouble();
    }

    public double getVolume()
    {
        volume = (pi * radius * radius) * height;
        return volume;
    }

    public double getPerimeter()
    {
        perimeter = 2 * pi * getRadius();
        return perimeter;
    }
    
    public void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("------------ This is a Circle ------------");
        System.out.format("Radius is %.2f", radius);
        System.out.format("Area is %.2f ", area);
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        
        
        System.out.println("----------- This is a Cylinder ------------");
        System.out.format("Radius is %.2f"+ getRadius());
        System.out.format("Volume is %.2f"+ getVolume());
        System.out.format("Perimeter is %.2f"+ perimeter);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello there, welcome to StackOverflow. On your main method, here are some steps for you to figure out. On your main method, wrap your code into a loop structure (search for it), add your question at the end of the loop, ask for the input, the loop should check the input

Answer (score 0):

you are not calling any of your custom methods in the main method. You should do that first then depending on your output you can tell what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: do you mean i should add something like cylinder c = new cylinder(); like this?

Comment: getRadius() is used in main method where is this method defined?

Answer (score 0):

```java
public void main(String args[]) {
    String reply = null;

    do {
        System.out.println("------------ This is a Circle ------------");
        System.out.format("Radius is %.2f", radius);
        System.out.format("Area is %.2f ", area);
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        
        
        System.out.println("----------- This is a Cylinder ------------");
        System.out.format("Radius is %.2f"+ getRadius());
        System.out.format("Volume is %.2f"+ getVolume());
        System.out.format("Perimeter is %.2f"+ perimeter);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("would you like to repeat this calculation ?(Y/N)");
                
        reply = input.next();
    } while(reply.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
}
```

Comment: the "reply"  in while appears as an error, do i need to declare it first?

Comment: Condition in `while` does not see your `reply` variable which is inside the loop

Comment: @nkrivenko i move the bracket beside 'String' but the error appears in the 'input.next();' is it because the input is outside the bracket? if i moved the bracket back it will state the 'reply' is the error.

Comment: Try the code now, it should work (don't forget to put a semicolon after `new Scanner(System.in);` though)